# Python: JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Need some expert help on how to debug this and force a double quotes where missing, so that i can get a successful response. It is throwing error here  df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(rt.json(), record_path='offers'). The josn looks fine i have staged into csv, so not sure where the issue is

**my Code**

```
import requests
import csv
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

url = "https://authentication.skiapi.com/access_token"

payload = {
    "client_id": "00c7fcf******",
    "client_secret": "7676cd5a********",
    "grant_type": "client_credentials"
}
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}

response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
r = response.json() 
access_token = r.get('access_token') 
print(response.json()['access_token'])

   uri = "https://private-anon-73f9ac5d87-slinksmerchantapi.apiary-mock.com/v4/publisher/12633/offers?country=US"
headers = {'Authorization': access_token,'Content-Type': "application/json"}
rt = requests.get(uri, headers=headers)
      
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(rt.json(), record_path='offers') ###problem is here 
#print(df)
df.to_csv(r"C:\\Users\ral\Downloads\\offers.csv", index=False)
```

**My Sample JSON**

```
{
    "has_more": true
    "offers": [{
        "coupon_code": null
        "terms": null
        "description": "40% Off Comforters & Other Cool Bedding Stuff Online at BoxLunch! Stock up on select blankets and bedding online only for a limited time -- See site for details. Valid 3/3-3/5"
        "offer_starts": "2017-03-03 08:00:00"
        "title": "40% Off Comforters & Other Cool Bedding Stuff Online at BoxLunch!"
        "url": "http://www.boxlunch.com/home/bedroom/?soffer=152034"
        "merchant_details": {
            "domain": "boxlunchgifts.com"
            "verticals": []
            "country_code": null
            "id": 393756
            "metadata": {}
            "favourite": false
            "partner_type": null
            "merchant_id": 383288
            "advertiser_id": 123456
            "name": "BoxLunch"
            "countries": []
            "domains": [
                "boxlunchgifts.com"
                "boxlunch.com"
            ]
        }
        "offer_type": "sale"
        "id": 152034
        "offer_ends": "2017-03-05 08:00:00"
    }]
    "last_val": 152034
    "next_val": 152032
    "num_returned": 1
}
```

Comment: @tdelaney .. no way.. i did scrub them..However i made edits to the post to avoid that confusion Thank you

Comment: Where is this sample json getting formed? It could be my own lack of knowledge, but the first thing I notice is that there are no commas delimiting the elements.  Something like that is something I'd imagine causes issues with a JSON decoder. More context around that sample json might help.

Comment: @Eddie it is a API call and the response is JSON. Is there a JSON formatter function we can use here? to ensure it is right JSON format

Comment: The json isn't valid. Commas at least are missing. You could `json.dump(rt.json(), open("rt.json", "w"), indent=4)` and then post that. Also, the exact python traceback is useful so we can see where the fail was.

Comment: Come to think of it, if the json decode is failing, `rt.content` or `rt.raw.read()` may be better.

Comment: ...and `rt.headers` is interesting, esp content-type, but the whole thing really.

Comment: @tdelaney Sorry Dump isnt working...so when i try json.dump(rt.raw.read(), open("rt.json", "w"), indent=4) i get TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable and json.dump(rt.headers(), open("rt.headers", "w"), indent=4) i get TypeError: 'CaseInsensitiveDict' object is not callable and this json.dump(rt.content(), open("rt.content", "w"), indent=4) i get TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable

Comment: You could make that `open("rt.content", "wb").write(rt.content)`.

Comment: The app may not be giving you json because of the header. You could add `'Accept': 'application/json'` to tell it you want json back. Any maybe spoof a browser type. This one used to work magic: `'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'`

Comment: That's strange. The returned header `rt.header` may help.

Comment: Oh, and you'd add those things to the `header` dict right before that requests.get all that returns rt.

Comment: Hmmm.... so, `rt` itself should still be there. You could see what `rt.content` and `rt.headers` display on screen. If you were doing this on the command line and the script was, say, `foo.py`, you could `python -i foo.py` to drop into the shell on completion. But since you are jupyter, the variable should be there to play with.

Comment: Oops, "headers".

Answer (score 1):

The JSON is not fine - as per comments commas are missing plus **true** should be **True** and **null** should be **None** in python

Additionally you are using deprecated interface to `json_normalize`

what does `json.dumps(rt.json(), indent=2)` return?  Valid json?

**patched json**

```
json = {
    "has_more": True,
    "offers": [{
        "coupon_code": None,
        "terms": None,
        "description": "40% Off Comforters & Other Cool Bedding Stuff Online at BoxLunch! Stock up on select blankets and bedding online only for a limited time -- See site for details. Valid 3/3-3/5",
        "offer_starts": "2017-03-03 08:00:00",
        "title": "40% Off Comforters & Other Cool Bedding Stuff Online at BoxLunch!",
        "url": "http://www.boxlunch.com/home/bedroom/?soffer=152034",
        "merchant_details": {
            "domain": "boxlunchgifts.com",
            "verticals": [],
            "country_code": None,
            "id": 393756,
            "metadata": {},
            "favourite": False,
            "partner_type": None,
            "merchant_id": 383288,
            "advertiser_id": 123456,
            "name": "BoxLunch",
            "countries": [],
            "domains": [
                "boxlunchgifts.com",
                "boxlunch.com"
            ]
        },
        "offer_type": "sale",
        "id": 152034,
        "offer_ends": "2017-03-05 08:00:00"
    }],
    "last_val": 152034,
    "next_val": 152032,
    "num_returned": 1
}
pd.json_normalize(json, record_path="offers")
```

Comment: when i execute this json.dumps(rt.json(), indent=2), i get JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 26 column 9 (char 1006)

Comment: ok - that's the real source of your issue.  the API is not providing valid JSON. If it's an internal service you should get API provider to fix the API.  external try raising a bug report against it